# Constructor / Destructor calling sequence in inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

Why order of constructors called in inheritance is reverse than calls to destructors ? Any specific reason ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is.  The order for constructors is `base`, `derived`.  This ensures that the constructor for `derived` can rely on `base` being properly initialised while the `derived` constructor runs.

The order for destructors is `derived`, `base`.  This ensures that `derived` can rely on `base` still being valid while the `derived` destructor runs.

Comment: Both the statements sounds same. My doubt is what is the dependency ? What can go wrong if base is destroyed first & then derived.

Comment: The `derived`destructor might, for example, call a method of `base`, and that might die horribly if `base` has already been destroyed.  OTOH, the `base` destructor cannot call a method of `derived`, so destroying `derived` first is safe.

Comment: Oh Ok. Now got it. Thanks.